# Argo Sensor Pod is not Running

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj, argo-events

I am trying to create a argo sensor, but its not bringing up any pod after applying using kubectl. kubectl resource has created successfully. Here is my applied yaml file. After applying it, i can see sensor object but no pod is running in cluster.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: kafka-event-sensors
  namespace: argo
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: dummy-kafka-event
      eventSourceName: kafka-event
      eventName: dummy-topic-event
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: kafka-workflow-trigger
        k8s:
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: kafka-workflow-
              spec:
                entrypoint: whalesay
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                    - name: message
                      # this is the value that should be overridden
                      value: hello world
                templates:
                  - name: whalesay
                    inputs:
                      parameters:
                        - name: message
                    container:
                      image: docker/whalesay:latest
                      command: [cowsay]
                      args: ["{{inputs.parameters.message}}"]
          parameters:
            - src:
                dependencyName: test-dep
                dataKey: body
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
```

Comment: What is the status of your controller-manager? Since that is the component responsible for managing the sensor object, it makes sense to first check that it's running properly and detects the new sensor object.

Comment: Hey! thank you for reply, i have applied yaml file, after that i was able to see sensor resource object in cluster. but not sensor pod. Is there any way to check status of controller-manager (by controller-manager did you mean by controller in master node ?)

Comment: I meant the controller argo uses to control argo sensors. You can probably find it in the same namespace argo is installed in, and see the status in its logs.

Comment: Thanks ! .... i got the issue, sensor-controller was not running. I was new to argo-events

Comment: Great to hear. I'll add it as the official answer and if you think it is the correct one please mark it as correct for future viewers

Answer (score 0):

The controller-manager is the component responsible for managing the sensor object, it makes sense to first check that it's running properly and detects the new sensor objects created on the cluster.